# Proving $\frac{a+b+c}{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+9}\ge \frac{abc+6}{abc+27}$ for $a, b, c\ge 0$; $ab + bc + ca = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I came up with the inequality accidentally so there is no original proof so far. It would be great if you can give some useful help to prove it.

> **Problem.** Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $ab+bc+ca=3.$ Prove that$$\frac{a+b+c}{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+9}\ge \frac{abc+6}{abc+27}.$$
> Equality occurs when $a=b=c=1$ or $a=3;b=1;c=0$ and its permutations.

I thought that $BW$ might be helpful for this case. See more about this method [AOPS.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084)

Firstly, I tried to verify the inequality as
$$abc(a+b+c)+27(a+b+c)\ge abc(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)+9abc+54+6(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a).$$
After homogenization, it's

$$\frac{abc(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}{3}+\sqrt{3}(a+b+c)\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)^5}$$
$$\ge abc(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)+\sqrt{3}abc\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)^3}+2(ab+bc+ca)^3+\frac{2\sqrt{3}(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)^3}}{3}.$$

Or $$3 abc(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)+6(ab+bc+ca)^3-abc(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\le \sqrt{3(ab+bc+ca)^3}\cdot\left[3(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-3abc-2(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)\right].$$

It's not hard to see that both side is non-negative sign.

Hence, it's enough to show a $12$th degree cyclic polynomial

$$3(ab+bc+ca)^3\cdot\left[3(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-3abc-2(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)\right]^2\ge \left[3 abc(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)+6(ab+bc+ca)^3-abc(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\right]^2.$$
I attach the result by Wolfram. [BW](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=3Power%5B%5C%2840%29xy%2Byz%2Bzx%5C%2841%29%2C3%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%293%5C%2840%29x%2By%2Bz%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29xy%2Byz%2Bzx%5C%2841%29-3xyz-2%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5Dy%2BPower%5By%2C2%5Dz%2BPower%5Bz%2C2%5Dx%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D-Power%5B%5C%2840%293xyz%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5Dy%2BPower%5By%2C2%5Dz%2BPower%5Bz%2C2%5Dx%5C%2841%29%2B6Power%5B%5C%2840%29xy%2Byz%2Bzx%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D-xyz%5C%2840%29x%2By%2Bz%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29xy%2Byz%2Bzx%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2844%29x%3Da%5C%2844%29y%3Da%2Bu%5C%2844%29z%3Da%2Bv)

I did not check all coefficient. In case it is true, the proof is still non-human proof, I think.

Also, I found an interesting fact which is simpler
$$\boxed{\color{green}{\frac{9(a+b+c)}{2}-\frac{3abc}{2}-9\ge a^2b+b^2c+c^2a}.}$$
This inequality saves desired occuring equality.

I try to use it for the starting inequality without success.

Indeed, we'll prove  $$\color{black}{\frac{a+b+c}{\dfrac{9(a+b+c)}{2}-\dfrac{3abc}{2}}\ge \frac{abc+6}{abc+27}}$$which is already wrong when $a=b\rightarrow 1^{-}.$

For this kind of inequalities, I'd like to study more about the relations of $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a, a+b+c,ab+bc+ca, abc.$

It is very useful if you can give some relevant links to topic.

I truly hope we can find some nice ideas for my inequality. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is a proof.*

If $abc = 0$, it is easy.

In the following, assume that $abc > 0$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$\frac{(a + b + c)(abc + 27)}{abc + 6} - 9 - (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a) 
\ge 0$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{(a + b + c)(abc + 27)}{abc + 6} - 9 - \frac{a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + (ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2)}{2} \\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \frac{a^2b + b^2c + c^2a - (ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2)}{2}\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{(a - b)(b - c)(a - c)}{2}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

It is easy to prove that
$$\frac{(a + b + c)(abc + 27)}{abc + 6} - 9 - \frac{a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + (ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2)}{2} \ge 0. \tag{2}$$
(One may use pqr method.)

From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\frac{(a + b + c)(abc + 27)}{abc + 6} - 9 - \frac{a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + (ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2)}{2} \right)^2\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \frac{(a - b)^2(b - c)^2(a - c)^2}{4}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

We use the pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 3, r = abc$. (3) is written as
\begin{align*}
  f(p) &:= \left( {r}^{3}+12\,{r}^{2}+36\,r \right) {p}^{3}+ \left( -2\,{r}^{2}-
 45\,r+243 \right) {p}^{2}\\
 &\qquad + \left( -15\,{r}^{3}-108\,{r}^{2}-432\,r-
 1944 \right) p\\
 &\qquad +9\,{r}^{4}+81\,{r}^{3}+108\,{r}^{2}+324\,r+3888 \\
 &\ge 0. \tag{4}
\end{align*}

If $r = 1$, we have $f(p) = 49(p+10)(p-3)^2 \ge 0$.

If $r \ne 1$, the discriminant of $f$ is give by $-27(r + 6)^2(r - 1)^2r g(r) < 0$ where
\begin{align*}
 g(r) &:= 81\,{r}^{9}+2592\,{r}^{8}+33340\,{r}^{7}+224198\,{r}^{6}+951556\,{r}^{
  5} +3657420\,{r}^{4}\\
 &\qquad +14070429\,{r}^{3}+34706232\,{r}^{2}+39602196\,r+
 10628820.
\end{align*}
Thus, the cubic equation $f(p)= 0$ has exactly one real root on $(-\infty, \infty)$.
Note that $f(0) > 0$ and $f(-\infty) = -\infty$.
Thus, $f(p) = 0$ has a negative real root.
Thus, $f(p) \ge 0$ for all $p \ge 0$.

We are done.

Comment: Yes (+1), I also found a relation between cyclic and symmetric yields now but the rest of idea is much calculate. Thank you.