# A nice 3 variable inhomogeneous asymmetric inequality by TATA box.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

This inequality is proposed by TATA box.

Prove that for ${\forall}a,b,c \geq 0$ such that $ab+bc+ca=2$, prove the following inequality.

$$\sum_{cyc}a^2 + abc \geq \frac{3}{8}\sum_{cyc}a^3 b +2$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the equality holds if and only if $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0),(1,0,2),(0,2,1)$. We prove this by using this condition.

**Step 1**

Note that the following holds. This is easy to think by the equality condition.

$$\sum_{cyc}ab(a-2b+c)^2 \geq 0$$

$$\bigg( \sum_{cyc}ab \bigg)^2 = 4$$

By homogenizing and clearing, it suffices to prove the following.

$$\sum_{cyc}ab(a-2b+c)^2 \geq abc(3\sum_{cyc}a -8)$$

Therefore, it suffices to prove when $\sum_{cyc}a > \frac{8}{3} $.

**Step 2**

Our goal is prove that at least one of the following holds.

$$(a-2b+c)^2 > c (3\sum_{cyc}a - 8)$$

$$(b-2c+a)^2 > a (3\sum_{cyc}a - 8)$$

$$(c-2a+b)^2 > b (3\sum_{cyc}a - 8)$$

Or it suffices to prove the following.

$$\sum_{cyc}(2a-b-c)^2 > (\sum_{cyc}a)(3\sum_{cyc}a - 8)$$

By clearing and using $ab+bc+ca=2$, it suffices to prove the below.

$$3\sum_{cyc}a^2 + 8\sum_{cyc}a > 24$$

This is true by $a+b+c > \frac{8}{3}$ and C-S inequality since the following.

$$3\sum_{cyc}a^2 + 8\sum_{cyc}a \geq (\sum_{cyc}a)^2+ \sum_{cyc}a >\frac{256}{9}>24$$

This proves the inequality.

Comment: I'm confusing about your Step 2.

Comment: Ok, now I full understand. Your idea is very good as usual.

Comment: It tried to use your bound for $\frac{a+b+c}{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+8}\ge \frac{1}{4}, \forall a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=2.$
But I got a weaker result.

Comment: @TATAbox Nice try! Thanks. Is the problem above valid?

Comment: Yes, it is true by BW. Hope there is a nice proof for it.

Comment: @TATAbox The above is exactly the same as $\sum_{cyc}a(b+2c-2)^{2} \geq 0$.

Comment: I try to full expanding $$\iff a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+8\le 4abc+4(a+b+c)$$

Comment: @TATAbox You may use $2\sum_{cyc}a = \sum_{cyc}ab \sum_{cyc}a$