# Showing $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2b+16}\ge \frac{3}{16}$, for $a,b,c\ge 0$ and $ab+bc+ca=4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

> If $a,b,c\ge 0$ and $ab+bc+ca=4$, then prove $$\frac{a}{a^2b+16}+\frac{b}{b^2c+16}+\frac{c}{c^2a+16}\ge \frac{3}{16}$$

It is from Pham Kim Hung (in a Knot text).

Equality case is $(a,b,c)=(4,1,0)$. A big trouble is around $a=b=c=\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Can you help me prove it?