# About a cyclic inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2+3\ge 2\sqrt{2(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)+3abc}.$

Tags: inequality

I am looking for a proof. Here is my question.

> **Problem.** Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $a+b+c=3.$ Prove that$$\color{black}{a^2+b^2+c^2+3\ge 2\sqrt{2(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)+3abc}. }\tag{1}$$
> Source: own

---

Equality holds iff $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1);(2,1,0)$ or its cyclic permutations.

I came up with this inequality from a weaker one $$\color{black}{a^2+b^2+c^2+3\ge 2\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{a^3b+b^3c+c^3a}.}\tag{2}$$
Here is my two ideas for $(2).$

**Idea 1.**

Denote $a+b+c=3=p; ab+bc+ca=q; abc=r.$

Verifying $\sum_{cyc}a^3b\longrightarrow \sum_{cyc}a^2b,$

$$a^3b=\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}a^2b-\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2-abc\sum_{cyc}a=3\sum_{cyc}a^2b-q^2+3r$$
By a well-known result $$\boxed{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc\le \frac{4}{27}(a+b+c)^3, \forall a,b,c\ge 0. }\tag{*}$$

It remains to prove $$\color{black}{12-2q\ge 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{12-q^2}.}\iff (q-2)^2\ge 0.$$

*Remark $1$.*

The $(*)$ doesn't help for $(1)$ since $$\color{black}{12-2q\ge 2\sqrt{2(12-q^2)+3r}}$$is not true when $a=b\rightarrow 1^{-}.$

**Idea 2.**

We can use directly the following result (maybe own) $$\boxed{\color{black}{4(a+b+c)^4\ge 27[a^3b+b^3c+c^3a+(ab+bc+ca)^2], \forall a,b,c\ge 0. }}\tag{4}$$
It follows by [BW.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=4Power%5B%5C%2840%29x%2By%2Bz%5C%2841%29%2C4%5D-27%5C%2840%29Power%5B%5C%2840%29xy%2Byz%2Bzx%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bx%2C3%5Dy%2BPower%5By%2C3%5Dz%2BPower%5Bz%2C3%5Dx%5C%2841%29%5C%2844%29x%3Da%5C%2844%29y%3Da%2Bu%5C%2844%29z%3Da%2Bv)

*Remark $2$.*

The $(4)$ doesn't help for $(1)$ since both $(3)$ and $(4)$ is exactly same!

Equality holds at $a=b=c$ or $a=0;b=2c$ and permutations. Recently, I've realised that $$(a+b+c)(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc)=a^3b+b^3c+c^3a+(ab+bc+ca)^2\le \frac{4}{27}(a+b+c)^4.$$
In conclusion, the inequality $(2)$ is proven but the stronger version $(1)$ is not complete.

I think there's at least two proofs for $(1)$ and it will be posted soon. Now, I'd like to find nice ideas for starting inequality.

Any ideas and comments are welcome. Thank you for your interest.

---

Remark $3.$ Here is some relevant inequalities.

I check that$$\color{black}{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+3+(-6+2\sqrt{6})abc}{8}\ge \sqrt{\frac{a^3b+b^3c+c^3a}{8}}}$$which save two equality cases but it's not true.

Also, the following inequality is true and I hope it will be useful for $(1).$
$$\color{black}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge a^3b+b^3c+c^3a+abc+2.}$$
Equality also holds iff $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1);(2,1,0)$ or its cyclic permutations.

It is obvious by [BW.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=4Power%5B%5C%2840%29x%2By%2Bz%5C%2841%29%2C4%5D-27%5C%2840%29Power%5B%5C%2840%29xy%2Byz%2Bzx%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bx%2C3%5Dy%2BPower%5By%2C3%5Dz%2BPower%5Bz%2C3%5Dx%5C%2841%29%5C%2844%29x%3Da%5C%2844%29y%3Da%2Bu%5C%2844%29z%3Da%2Bv) Hope there's a good proof like [d8g3n1v9
's idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824076/minimizing-p-fracaaab2-fracbbbc2-fracccca2-when-abbcca), [similar problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4827419/a-nice-3-variable-inhomogeneous-asymmetric-inequality-by-tata-box/4827420?noredirect=1#comment10276197_4827420)

See also [Riverli's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822554/proving-fracabca2bb2cc2a9-ge-fracabc6abc27-for-a-b-c-ge) for an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:
\begin{align*} \left[a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{1}{3}\left(a+b+c \right)^2 \right]^2 -8\left(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a \right)-4abc\left(a+b+c \right) \\ = \frac{2}{27} \sum_{\text{cyc}}\left( a-2b+4c\right)^2 \left(b+c-2a \right)^2, \end{align*}
which directly implies the result.

Comment: SOS solution. It is an easy one. I also found one: Your LHS $$= \frac13\, \left( 2\,{a}^{2}-3\,ab-ac-2\,{b}^{2}+4\,bc \right) ^{2}+\frac19\,
 \left( 2\,a-b-c \right) ^{2} \left( a-2\,b+4\,c \right) ^{2}
.$$

Comment: Wow, very nice SOS expression!

Comment: @RiverLi Do you think BW work?

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, BW works.

Comment: @RiverLi Nice. I found that there was a relation between these expressions, $x^2+y^2+z^2=2 \left(\frac{x}{2} +y \right)^2+\frac{3}{2}x^2$, where $x+y+z=0$.

Comment: @RiverLi It remains to prove $4\cdot\left[9a^2(u^2-uv+v^2)+3a(2u^3-9u^2v+9uv^2+2v^3)+(u-2v)^2(4u^2+2uv+v^2)\right]\ge 0.$

Comment: @TATAbox Then we need to show $\Delta_a \le 0$, Wolfram Alpha should help with factorizing.

Comment: @BabyLE Thank you. It's really helpful

Comment: @RiverLi May I ask you how did you find SOS expression?

Comment: @TATAbox You may read something about SOS, e.g. https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/sos_slides.pdf

Answer (score 0):

My proof using BW for $(1).$

After homogenization$$\color{black}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)^2\ge 6\cdot\sqrt{2(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)+abc(a+b+c)}.}$$
WLOG, assuming $a=\min\{a,b,c\}.$ Let $b=a+u; c=a+v (a,u,v\ge 0).$

We obtain$$\left[3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)^2\right]^2-36\left[2(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)+abc(a+b+c)\right]$$
$$=4\cdot\left[9a^2(u^2-uv+v^2)+3a(2u^3-9u^2v+9uv^2+2v^3)+(u-2v)^2(4u^2+2uv+v^2)\right].$$A big trouble is here$$2u^3-9u^2v+9uv^2+2v^3=2v^3+u(u-3v)(2u-3v).$$We can continue the approach due to discriminant theory.

Indeed, let $u=xv; x\ge 0.$ Now, we consider $$f(a)=9a^2(u^2-uv+v^2)+3a(2u^3-9u^2v+9uv^2+2v^3)+(u-2v)^2(4u^2+2uv+v^2)$$is a quadratic equation of $a$ where
$$\Delta_{a}=9\left[(2u^3-9u^2v+9uv^2+2v^3)^2-4(u-2v)^2(4u^2+2uv+v^2)(u^2-uv+v^2)\right]$$
$$=-27v^6 (x - 2)^2 (x + 1)^2 (2 x - 1)^2\le 0.$$Thus $f(a)\ge 0$ and we are done!